# I need to hide ListView columns in activity_view_record.xml when a TextView in content_main.xml is empty

Tags: android-listview, show-hide, listviewitem

I have an app that allows the user to list up to 10 medications. 
If the user enters only a couple medications, the resulting listview shows empty columns.
Specifically, I need to hide ListView columns in activity_view_record.xml when a TextView in content_main.xml is empty.
If StackOverflow has taught me nothing else, it's that somebody out there has already figured this out.
Looking forward to your response. 
Here are the details. 
ListView items are defined in activity_view_record.xml
...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/medication1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/medication2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/medication3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

...
ListView column "headers" are defined in content_main.xml 
...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/med1_textview"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/med2_textview"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/med3_textview"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

...
I hid empty "headers" in content_main.xml with this code in onCreate
...

```
if (med1_textview.getText().length() == 0){
    med1_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
if (med2_textview.getText().length() == 0){
    med2_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
if (med3_textview.getText().length() == 0){
    med3_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

...
Now I want to hide ListView columns associated these headers. I tried:
...

```
if (med1_textview.getText().length() == 0){
    med1_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    medication1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

...
No joy. 
After spending a couple of days on StackOverflow, I found the following suggestions:
...

setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_record);

...
or
...

listView.Columns.Item(3).Width=0;

...
or
...

listView.Columns.RemoveAt(3);

...
But they didn't say where or how to use the code.
I tried the following:
...

```
 if (med1_textview.getText().length() == 0){
        med1_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listView.Columns.Item(3).Width=0;
    }
```

...
and 
...

```
if (med1_textview.getText().length() == 0){
    med1_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    listView.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
}
```

...
Get the following error from Android Studio "Cannot resolve symbol 'Columns'" 
ListView documentation says nothing about columns, so I'm assuming it's an adapter issue

Columns are listed in public class MainActivity as
...

```
final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.medication1, R.id.medication2, R.id.medication3, //and so forth//};
```

...
The following is in MainActivity onCreate
...

```
dbManager = new DbManager(this);
dbManager.open();
Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();

listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_view_record, cursor, from, to, 0);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

...

Comment: After more research l have isolated the problem to the simplecurseradapter. A cursor adapter will give me more control over the listview. Any advice as to how to proceed?